# Demeaning a dataset by a group in a polars dataframe

Tags: dataframe, rust

I'm trying to demean a set of variables in some matrix called "X" by a grouping variable named "groups" in Rust Polars. I can't seem to understand how to do it in an efficient way.

I'm a Rust newbie and what I've done in the past (in python, though) is something along the lines of:

```
data.groupby("groups").transform(lambda x: x - x.mean())
```

Is there a similar way to do this in polars in Rust?

Below is a (hopefully reproducible) code snippet of what I've done so far that creates an X with random uniform data and randomly assigns groups to that X.

My first attempt was to try to do it all in one chain, but that failed, so in the below code, I'm trying to get the means in `out_mean` and subtract it from the original dataframe, although that's not ideal and it would be cool to have a chaining solution.

```
use ndarray::{Array, Array1,s};
use ndarray_rand::RandomExt;
use ndarray_rand::rand_distr::Uniform;
use polars::prelude::*;
extern crate random_choice;
use self::random_choice::random_choice;

fn main() {
    let X = Array::random((1000,10), Uniform::new(0,100));

    let samples = vec!["group 1", "group 2", "group 3"];
    let weights = vec![1.0,1.0,1.0];

    let groups: Vec<&&str> = random_choice().random_choice_f64(&samples, &weights, 1000);

    let groups_clone: Vec<&str> = groups.into_iter().copied().collect();

    let X_df = df!(
        "shock_1" =>  X.slice(s![..,0]).to_vec(),
        "shock_2" =>  X.slice(s![..,1]).to_vec(),
        "shock_3" =>  X.slice(s![..,2]).to_vec(),
        "groups" => &groups_clone
    );

    let out_means = 
        X_df
        .expect("error")
        .clone()
        .lazy()
        .select([
            all().mean().over(["groups"])
            ])
        .collect();


    println!("{:?}", X_df.expect("ERROR").sub(out_means))
```

FYI: I also installed the "dataframe_arithmetic" feature flag for polars

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this does what you're looking for. The “trick” is to not subtract two LazyFrames, but rather subtract expressions within the same LazyFrame.

```ini
# Cargo.toml
[dependencies]
    ndarray = "0.15.6"
    ndarray-rand = "0.14.0"
    polars = { version = "0.30.*", features = ["lazy"] }
```

```rust
// main.rs
fn main() {
    let x = Array::random((1000, 10), Uniform::new(0, 100));

    let samples = vec!["group 1", "group 2", "group 3"];
    let weights = vec![1.0, 1.0, 1.0];

    let mut rng = thread_rng();
    let dist = WeightedIndex::new(weights).unwrap();
    let groups = (0..1000)
        .map(|_| samples[dist.sample(&mut rng)])
        .collect::<Vec<_>>();

    let demeaned_df = df!(
        "shock_1" =>  x.slice(s![..,0]).to_vec(),
        "shock_2" =>  x.slice(s![..,1]).to_vec(),
        "shock_3" =>  x.slice(s![..,2]).to_vec(),
        "groups" => &groups
    )
    .unwrap()
    .lazy()
    .select([
        all().exclude(["groups"]) - all().exclude(["groups"]).mean().over(["groups"]),
        col("groups"),
    ])
    .collect()
    .unwrap();

    println!("{:?}", demeaned_df);
}
```

```
shape: (1_000, 4)
┌───────────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────┐
│ shock_1   ┆ shock_2    ┆ shock_3    ┆ groups  │
│ ---       ┆ ---        ┆ ---        ┆ ---     │
│ f64       ┆ f64        ┆ f64        ┆ str     │
╞═══════════╪════════════╪════════════╪═════════╡
│ 25.4375   ┆ 37.5125    ┆ -0.4375    ┆ group 2 │
│ 37.4375   ┆ 3.5125     ┆ 46.5625    ┆ group 2 │
│ 23.169643 ┆ 46.636905  ┆ 37.422619  ┆ group 3 │
│ 35.169643 ┆ 20.636905  ┆ -49.577381 ┆ group 3 │
│ …         ┆ …          ┆ …          ┆ …       │
│ -29.5625  ┆ -6.4875    ┆ -41.4375   ┆ group 2 │
│ -24.5625  ┆ 42.5125    ┆ -40.4375   ┆ group 2 │
│ 7.813953  ┆ -10.784884 ┆ -6.479651  ┆ group 1 │
│ 4.4375    ┆ 16.5125    ┆ 28.5625    ┆ group 2 │
└───────────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────┘
```